# Is temporary I-551 still valid upon passport renewal?

Tags: visas, usa, passport-renewals

So I got a temporary I-551 stamp on my passport after my two-year conditional green card has expired. Now, if I renew my passport (get a new passport and void the old one), will the stamp on the old passport still be valid?

I know that for visas, USCIS says you are fine as long as you have both the new and old passports. But does the same goes for I-551 stamp? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Anecdotal evidence shows that similar conditions also apply to an I-551 on an expired passport:

http://britishexpats.com/forum/us-immigration-citizenship-visas-34/i-551-expired-passport-526586/

> It is common practice to have a valid visa or other stamp in an
>   expired passport and to have a valid passport.

http://www.laborlawtalk.com/showthread.php?t=54087

> A cancelled passport doesn't matter as long as the stamp is valid and
>   unexpired.

In some cases, although from other source this appears to be very much an exception, **sometimes** the I-551 will be stamped on an already expired passport:

http://www.foreignborn.com/visas_imm/immigrant_visas/green_cards/3renew_greencard.htm

> NOTE: If you present an expired passport the USCIS will stamp it;
>   however, it will not be acceptable for employment verification
>   purposes.

https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/can-i-get-a-green-card-with-expired-passport--1072955.html

> You can get your green card with the expired passport. As my colleague
>   just stated, you should bring the passport, your visa, and your I-94
>   card with you to your interview with the immigration officer. If you
>   are approved at the interview, the officer can give you a stamp in
>   your passport (called an I-551 stamp) to show that you have a green
>   card while you wait for the actual card to come in the mail. In my
>   experience, officers will put these stamps in expired passports so
>   that you can show proof of status while you wait.

Hopefully someone can come along with a more definitive answer, but in the meantime you can at least have the results from a little google searching...